# window.location.href redirects to blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, window.location

I'm building a website (http://brandonbarber.co/) that looks like this.

[image]

And I have the following code for detecting a click on the linkedin div, it then redirects.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#linkedin").click(function(){
            window.location.href = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/brandon-barber-79043593/";
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
<div id="banner">
<div class="menubutton" id="home">Home</div>
<div class="menubutton" id="circuitry">Circuitry</div>
<div class="menubutton" id="programming">Programming</div>
<div class="menubutton" id="stackoverflow">Stackoverflow</div>
<div class="menubutton" id="linkedin">Linkin</div>
</div>
```

But when I click the div, it redirects to a blank page.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Why aren't you saying `location.href = ...`? Using `$(location).attr("href",...)` is kind of an odd way to do it. (Also the `location` object has a *property* `href`, not an *attribute*.) Also, why aren't you using (styled) anchor elements? Your page won't work for users who can't (or don't) use a mouse or other pointing device.

Comment: @nnnnnn It doesn't work either. Same thing, a blank page.

Comment: Try location.assign("xx"); or just location = "xx";  either way will work for you

Comment: @BryanEuton Doesn't work. Still a blank page.

Comment: The same code (from your updated question) works fine for me.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'll set the code set to window.location.href right now. You can try it on my site. It really doesn't work

Comment: Looking at your site, it isn't exactly a blank page.  It gives an error message that "/xx" can't be found.  I'm not at a computer atm so I can't figure it out for you.  It looks like the link isn't correct.

Comment: The problem on your site is **the frames** - check the dev console: `"Refused to display 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/brandon-barber-79043593/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."` (*Always* check the dev console for errors if something is behaving unexpectedly.)

Comment: @BryanEuton I know your not a computer atm. I just tried it on my iPhone, and it doesn't do anything. It doesn't change at all.

Comment: Frames are deprecated. This is 2016 not 1996. No need to use them in this day and age

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue occurs because your entire site is made up of frames/iframes, so when you use window.location.href = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/brandon-barber-79043593/" you'll prompt the browser to open that page in the iframe which isn't allowed by the source, in this case linkedin.
`Refused to display 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/brandon-barber-79043593/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

To work around this issue you'll need to use [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) instead of window.location, e.g:
`window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/in/brandon-barber-79043593/', '_blank');`

On a side note, I would recommend to not iframe the source content of the page and instead setting up a CNAME for your for your domain which points at your IP, because the IP is concurrently exposed in the DOM.

Answer (score -3):

This is actually legit code.

I copied it exactly as is on my server and it works!

http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_18/jquery.html

Maybe your internet connections...

nnnnnn is right, it's your frames!

From Mozilla :

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.linkedin.com/in/brandon-barber-79043593/ does not permit cross-origin framing.

Comment: How come x-frames are auto put in?